# JavaScript: Get clearname if it has a flatrate on one field

Tags: javascript, axios

I have the following JSON:

```js
[{
  id: 8,
  technical_name: "netflix",
  short_name: "nfx",
  clear_name: "Netflix",
  priority: 10,
  display_priority: 1,
  monetization_types: [ "flatrate" ],
}, {
  id: 9,
  technical_name: "gas",
  short_name: "gsx",
  clear_name: "Gas",
  priority: 10,
  display_priority: 1,
  monetization_types: [ "flatrate" ],
}, {
  id: 10,
  technical_name: "FOM",
  short_name: "Fom",
  clear_name: "Gas",
  priority: 10,
  display_priority: 1,
  monetization_types: [ "sax" ],
}]
```

Using axios I am trying to get all "clear_name" if the item has "flatrate" on its "monetization_types".
And then console.log it to the screen.

So far here's my code:

```
async function makeGetRequest() {
  let res = await axios.get("http://apis.makersla.com/content/providers/locale/it_IT");

  let data = res.data;
  jData = data.forEach((item) =>
    item.monetization_types.includes("flatrate") ? item.clear_name : ""
  );
  console.log(jData);
}

makeGetRequest();
```

But this doesn't work. Any idea how can I attain this? I just want to console log the clear name.

Comment: `.forEach()` doesn't return anything. You want `.reduce()` or `.filter()` + `.map()` or make `jData` an array and `.push()` the `clear_name` when necessary into it (assumption: you don't want a bunch of empty strings in the result)

Comment: So how exactly can I do it? And thank you for the thumbs down guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter and map:

```js
const data = [{ id: 8, technical_name: "netflix", short_name: "nfx", clear_name: "Netflix", priority: 10, display_priority: 1, monetization_types: [ "flatrate" ], }, { id: 9, technical_name: "gas", short_name: "gsx", clear_name: "Gas", priority: 10, display_priority: 1, monetization_types: [ "flatrate" ], }, { id: 10, technical_name: "FOM", short_name: "Fom", clear_name: "Gas", priority: 10, display_priority: 1, monetization_types: [ "sax" ], }];

const names = data
  .filter(({monetization_types}) => monetization_types && Array.isArray(monetization_types) && monetization_types.includes("flatrate"))
  .map(({clear_name}) => clear_name);

console.log(names)
```

Comment: `script.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null
    at script.js:6
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)`

Comment: Not with the object you posted in your question

Comment: So EITHER you do note get an array in all cases OR your JS implementation does not support Array.includes